# construct a representation of a $C^*$ algebra

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

If $A$ has a tracial state,we can construct a representation $(\pi,H)$ by the GNS theorem.
My question is: If $A$ has no tracial states,how can we construct a representation of $A$?Do there exist general methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GNS construction works for any positive linear functional (not just tracial states), and every $C^*$-algebra has plenty of positive linear functionals.